# tf-idf function in python need help to satisfy my output

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tf-idf

i've written a function that basically calculates the inverse document frequency (log base 10 ( total no.of documents/ no.of documents that contain a particular word))

My code:

```
def tfidf(docs,doc_freqs):
    res = []
    t = sum(isinstance(i, list) for i in docs)
    for key,val in doc_freqs.items():
        res.append(math.log10(t/val))
    pos = defaultdict(lambda:[])
    for docID, lists in enumerate(docs):
        for element in set(lists):
            pos[element].append([docID] + res)
    return pos
```

My output:

```
index = tfidf([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']], {'a': 2., 'b': 1., 'c': 1.})
index['a']
[[0, 0.0, 0.3010299956639812, 0.3010299956639812], [1, 0.0, 0.3010299956639812, 0.3010299956639812]]
index['b']
[[0, 0.0, 0.3010299956639812, 0.3010299956639812]]
```

Desired output:

```
index = tfidf([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a']], {'a': 2., 'b': 1., 'c': 1.})
index['a']
[[0, 0.0], [1, 0.0]]
index['b']
[[0, 0.3010299956639812]]
```

So basically i only want to display the docid in which that term occurs followed by its idf value alone. (i.e,) in the above example since term'a' occurs in both the documents the idf value is 0 .

Can anyone suggest what modifications i need to make in my code to print only the corresponding idf values according to the term specified at run time ??

Please help !!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolf,

Right now you are appending the entirety of `res` to the `[docID]`, but you only care about the value associated with that `element`. I suggest changing `res` to a `dict` like the following code:

```
import math

def tfidf(docs,doc_freqs):
    res = {}
    t = sum(isinstance(i, list) for i in docs)
    for key,val in doc_freqs.items():
        res[key] = math.log10(t/val)
    pos = defaultdict(lambda:[])
    for docID, lists in enumerate(docs):
        for element in set(lists):
            pos[element].append([docID, res[element]])
    return pos

docs = [['a', 'b', 'a'], ['a']]
doc_freqs = {'a': 2., 'b': 1., 'c': 1.}

index = tfidf(docs, doc_freqs)
```

This is then your output:

```
index['a']
[[0, 0.0], [1, 0.0]]

index['b']
[[0, 0.3010299956639812]]
```